# Activerecord select columns from a triple join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models `Passenger, Taxi, Order` i want to get a certain column of these tables. I used this to join them successfully.

```
Taxi.joins(:orders => :passenger).where(:taxi =>{:taxi_id =>2 } )
```

I want to select some of the columns of passenger table and some of the column of order,
but i do not know how can i do that?

The other problem is that, the result of this query is only columns of Taxi and not the column of `taxi+order+passenger`

I think i have a problem with my query

Comment: `Taxi.joins(orders: :passenger).where(taxi: {taxi_id: 2 } ).select('passengers.column_name, orders.column_name')`

Comment: I find out that my query only gives me the records related to the Taxi only,
somthing like leftjoin

Comment: specify the problem more and I'll give you the answer how to achieve. Comment on what is working/not working.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko   i edited my question

Comment: did you get it working? Please let me know if my answer was helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
Taxi
  .joins(orders: :passenger)
  .where(taxi: {taxi_id: 2 })
  .pluck('passengers.column_name, orders.column_name')
```

Comment: This answer helped me. I had a join of two tables where only the columns of the first table appeared. Adding pluck solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Taxi.joins(orders: :passenger).where(taxi:{taxi_id: 2}).includes(orders: :passenger).map do |taxi|
  #this will not query again as the includes directive above already fetched
  taxi.orders.map {|p| puts p}  
end
```